# How to Query 2 SQL databases and compare results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 separate SQL Server databases i'd like to query and compare the results.

For example:

DB1

```
Select * 
from Customers 
where dtcreated > @startdate
```

This query will give me a list of customers who were created after a specific date.

I would then like to take the results above, and query another database (DB2) to tell me which of the above query customers are still active.

Something like:

DB2

```
Select * 
From Customers
Where bactive = 'True'
      (and exists in DB1 query)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Output:

```
Number of Records from DB1            Number Active in DB2
        155                                   67
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do cross-database queries by specifying the databasename and the schema + table name.

```
Select * 
From Customers b
Where bactive = 'True'
and exists
(Select 'x' from 
database1.dbo.Customers A
where a.dtcreated > @startdate
and a.key = b.key)
```

I'm sorry but i'm a bit confused by the example querys and example output. But using this technique you can count any way you like

Comment: What is `and a.key = b.key`?

Comment: well, if you want to check if a customer from database A exists in database B you will need to have a key or a set of fields to join on, to make sure that you're talking about the same customer. More specifically, how do you know the customer is the same in both databases

Comment: Tom V.  Sorry for the confusion, just wanted to give you a sense of what it was I was looking for.  In any event, your information got me to my answer.  the a.key = b.key was the missing piece in everything I was trying. Thank you!

Comment: @Shmewnix make sure that all fields that you use in the where clause are indexed, otherwise on large databases this query could take ages :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Select * 
From db2.dbo.Customers
Where bactive = 'True'
and exists(Select * from db1.dbo.Customers where dtcreated > @startdate)
```

Comment: for this query you will have to make sure that `bactive` and `dtcreated` are properly indexed, or this query could run really, really slow on large tables